After switching to Spectrum, I can no longer access any Raspberry Pi using its IP address
After switching from Hotwire to Spectrum, I can't access any of my Raspberry Pi's using their new IP addresses:

All of my other devices, including Mac and Windows, can be contacted fine, but for some reason, I can't access either of my two RPi's through VNC, ssh, ping, or a simple web server (all of which I could do before)

Why is this happening? 

Additional information:

Old IP: 192.168.7.175/24

New IP: 192.168.1.15/24


$ ping 192.168.1.15 

  PING 192.168.1.15 (192.168.1.15): 56 data bytes

    Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
    ping: sendto: No route to host

    Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
    ping: sendto: Host is down

    Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
    ping: sendto: Host is down

    Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
    ping: sendto: Host is down

    Request timeout for icmp_seq 4



$ ssh pi@192.168.1.15

  ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.15 port 22: Host is down





On the machine trying to connect to 192.168.1.15 what is the IP address?

That would be my mac. It's 192.168.1.176

I assume you have tried rebooting the target device? How did you confirm the device was assigned 192.168.1.15?

Yes, it has been rebooted 3 times successfully without any issues. I used ip addr to find its IP address (which is the same thing I did on mac) and I used the wifi GUI to view the IP address.

So you have access to a local console on the device, that's good information. Are you able to ping your gateway from the device?  Are you able to ping the device from your gateway?

Never tried that yet, but yes. I just tried it and I am able to ping the gateway from the pi, but not vice-versa.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Have you confirmed SSHd is running on the Pi and listening to the expected interface:port? Is the Pi wired or wireless? If wireless, perhaps your wifi is set to isolate clients?

The pi is wireless. I realized that Spectrum has network isolation enabled by default with their routers. The only solution is to get my own router.

I’m voting to close this question because “Spectrum has network isolation enabled by default with their routers. The only solution is to get my own router.”

Always run your own router if you want to be able to have a functional home network.
